# Controlling $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\sin(x)^{d-2}\ dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

The last remaining piece of a statement i am trying to prove is causing me difficulties. For natrual $d$,
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\sin(x)^{d-2}\ dx<\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin(x)^{d-2}\ dx$$
obviously holds by monotonicty. However, i need the somewhat stronger version
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\sin(x)^{d-2}\ dx\leq\frac{\pi}{2}\left(1-\frac{C}{\sqrt{d}}\right)\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin(x)^{d-2}\ dx$$
where C is some positive constant.

I don't quite know how to tackle this issue. By adjusting $C$, one can clearly handle $\sin(x)^d$ equivalently. Moreover, there are some Gamma function estimates one can rely on for the upper bound, but i couldn't find any meaningful results on the integration of $xsin(x)^d$. Is the above statement even true?

Comment: note that $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(x)^a\cos(x)^bdx=\frac12\text{B}\bigg(\frac{a+1}2,\frac{b+1}2\bigg)$$ where $B$ is the Euler Beta function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follows from
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\Big)\sin^{d-2}x\,dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\cos^{d-2}x\,dx\in\Big(I_d,\frac{\pi}{2}I_d\Big),$$
where $I_d=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{d-2}x\sin x\,dx=\frac{1}{d-1}$, as $\sin x < x < \dfrac{\pi}{2}\sin x$ for $0<x<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Actually, if $C_d$ makes it an equality, then it is easy to show that $\displaystyle\lim_{d\to\infty}C_d=\Big(\frac{2}{\pi}\Big)^{3/2}$.